# Reversing an integer in binary representation

Tags: java, stack, push, reverse

I tried to create a code to take in a whole number in Java and output it in binary. The problem would seem that the binary is printing out backward. For instance, `6` should output as `011` but comes out as `110`.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int userNum;

    Scanner in =new Scanner(System. in );

    userNum = in.nextInt();

    binary(userNum);
    System.out.print("\n");
  }

  private static void binary(int userNum) {
    int remainder;

    while (userNum <= 1) {
      System.out.print(userNum);
      return;
    }

    remainder = userNum % 2;
    binary(userNum >> 1);
    System.out.print(remainder);
  }
}
```

I tried incorporating a push stack to push the remainder into a stack that I can pull later, but couldn't quite get it to land.

```java
private static void reverse(int userNum) {

  String backwards;

  while (userNum >= 0) {
    backwards.push(int userNum);
    System.out.println(backwards);
    return;
  }
}
```

It is part of a class assignment which asks the following.

> Write a program that takes in a positive integer as input, and outputs a string of 1's and 0's representing the integer in binary. For an integer x, the algorithm is:

```
As long as x is greater than 0
   Output x % 2 (remainder is either 0 or 1)
   x = x / 2
```

Note: The above algorithm outputs the 0's and 1's in reverse order.

Ex: If the input is:

`6`

the output is:

`011`

`6` in binary is `110`; the algorithm outputs the bits in reverse.

These are the tests the program applies and my results.

Input `6`

Your output `binary is:110`

Expected output `011`

Input `19`

Your output `10011`

Expected output `11001`

Input `255`

Your output `11111111`

Expected output `11111111`

Any help or guidance in this, I would be greatly appreciative of it.

Comment: Why 6 should be printed as `011`?  `110` is correct

Comment: Binary value of 6 is 110. Why do want to reverse it?

Comment: I'm taking a class and the question itself might be bugged. I'll update the question with the assignment question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Per the requirement and not taking into consideration of negative numbers

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int userNum;

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        userNum = scnr.nextInt();

        while(userNum > 0){
            System.out.print(userNum % 2);
            userNum = userNum / 2;
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: As per requirement, this seems to be the simplest answer.

Answer (score 0):

First using predefined method then a custom one.

```
public class IntToBinary {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int decimalNumber = 10;

        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(decimalNumber));

        System.out.println(convertBinary(10));
    }

    public static String convertBinary(int num) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int binary[] = new int[40];
        int index = 0;
        while (num > 0) {
            binary[index++] = num % 2;
            num = num / 2;
        }
        for (int i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            sb.append(binary[i]);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: When using his own code I managed to get the same results. So I just supplied alternative methods if he wanted to see what the results were. As for the StringBuilder and array, I just wanted to return a string for use

Answer (score 0):

Your program appears to work fine for positive values.  However it does not handle negative numbers which have their own unique binary representation known as [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).  You could do something like the following to accommodate:

```
private static void binary(int userNum) {
    int remainder;

   //  while (userNum <= 1) {
   //     System.out.print(userNum);
   //     return;
   // }
   if (userNum == 0) {
          return;
    }

    // simply mask off the bit instead of dividing by two
    remainder = userNum & 1;
    // and shift right thru the sign bit
    binary(userNum >>> 1);
    System.out.print(remainder);    
}
}

binary(-6));
```

prints

```
11111111111111111111111111111010
```

And the reason these printed out in proper order is because your routine is recursive.  That is a natural behavior of printing the values stored in the stack from a recursive procedure.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reverse_BinaryNum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Type your code here. */

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        int inputNum;

        System.out.println("Enter the Digit : ");
        inputNum = scnr.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The Reverse Binary for the given Digit is : ");
        while (inputNum > 0) {
            System.out.print(inputNum % 2);
            inputNum = inputNum / 2;

        }
        scnr.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. It's nice to try to help others but remember that it's better to add some explanation for your answer. Also make sure to read: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct.